# How to get a table to refresh in a Tab Control

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a tabbed control with two tabs, one called add and the other called delete, I have a table in a form on the delete tab showing all the added records but how do I get this table to refresh when the tab is selected.

I have tried adding a run command refresh macro to the on click of the delete tab. I have also tried me.labourform.requery and none of these refresh the table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `Click` event, try using the `Change` event.  For example:

```
Private Sub TabCtl1_Change()
    Select Case TabCtl1.Pages.Item(TabCtl1.Value).name

    Case "delete"
        Me.labourform.Requery
    Case Else
    End Select
End Sub
```